# API calls are not happning in flutter release APK

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-release

I am developing an app in Flutter while developing the APP is working as excepted, but once generated a release APK (Android studio -> Build -> Flutter -> Build APK).
After installing release APK, API calls are not happning

- I have added internet permissions in manifest
- Added a key store in the release build type.

Flutter release APK should work as like debug APK

Comment: Unless we're omniscient, we're going to need some more information to help :) Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details, especially regarding a minimum reproducible example!

Answer (score 0):

I think can you check your gradle file with property

Change from

`signingConfig signingConfigs.debug`

to

`signingConfig signingConfigs.release`

So your (build.gradle) will look like below

`buildTypes { release {  signingConfig signingConfigs.release } }`